# PHP file not found when sending hebrew value parameter

Tags: wordpress, character-encoding

I have a form which sending his values to an ajax php.
When the values are in hebrew, I get 404 for the php file. 
When the value are in english - everything is OK.
The varaible is "question".
This is how the "GET" look like when looking on firebug.
Hebrew version (look at the "question" parameter) :

```
http://ilanerez.co.il/wp-content/plugins/wp-faq/wp-faq-ajax.php?cmd=ask&uninumber=74db12&74db12%5Bgroup_id%5D=2&74db12%5Bemail%5D=dsssf%40sdfsd.com&74db12%5Bquestion%5D=%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%95%D7%9F
```

English and working "GET":

```
http://ilanerez.co.il/wp-content/plugins/wp-faq/wp-faq-ajax.php?cmd=ask&uninumber=74db12&74db12%5Bgroup_id%5D=&74db12%5Bemail%5D=sfdss%40sdfs.com&74db12%5Bquestion%5D=sdf
```

It used to work , and suddenly it stopped working.
Should I encode the data before sending the form? 
Because I don't able to encode it afterwards because I don't get the php file.
Do you have any idea? thanks

Comment: You seem to be missing the `http://` from the first.  Is this a copy/paste mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had a WordPress plugin activated called: Better WP Security .
Which had "Filter suspicious query string" feature turned on.
I disabled it and it solved the problem.